# PXE (network) boot a computer with no or broken PXE support

Tags: pxe

Trying to PXE boot a device that just tries IPv4 and IPv6 and gives up few minutes later.

I came across iPXE and netboot.xyz  trying to use them to get the computer to boot, and I got to a CLI.  I brought up help which is just a list of commands.  I got the info dumps on several commands and tried every reasonable option and they all failed.

Once at the command line how do I boot from a pre-existing PXE boot which works on every other PC just not a few.

Booting with an ISO that allows PXE booting seemed the most logical course of action.

The network adapter connects to the network fine, it just doesn't PXE boot.  The device has a single USB port which I had to use a hub for the network adapter and a USB thumb drive.

(Obviously I am not posting the real IP address)

I tried

```
autoboot
chain 1.1.1.1
chain 1.1.1.1/smsboot/something.efi
chain tftp://1.1.1.1/smsboot/something.efi
 more variations on the same theme.
```

> Is PXE set up on your network (DHCP and TFTP and all)? Can other
> devices boot using PXE?

Yes, 100's of other devices successfully PXE boot all the time.

> What are you hoping to boot using PXE?

A microsoft surface 3m (I believe), and yes I have the proriatory microsoft USB type dongle.  The one MS says you have to buy.

Comment: Get the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App on a bootable USB Key.  Test the hardware.  There appears to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Its out of warranty, and so even if it is a hardware issue it won't get fixed, and nobody is willing to pay out of pocket to fix it.

Comment: Warranty is not normally an issue to get a diagnostic app. You need to test it. If broken you will need to replace it.

Comment: The reason I am focusing on iPXE or etc is because I am sure it is the hardware and no one with spend money to replace it.

Comment: Does that device support any kind of portable storage ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc It has a single USB port.

Comment: I think your description is too light in details. When using iPXE, what CLI did you get? What exact commands did you try and what was the output? What are you hoping to boot using PXE? Is PXE set up on your network (DHCP and TFTP and all)? Can other devices boot using PXE?

Comment: @DanielB  I have added details.

Comment: I see you are attempting to boot using EFI executables. UEFI NetBoot is distinct from PXE. Are you starting iPXE in UEFI mode?

Comment: @DanielB  Yes, ideally.  I want to PXE boot and PXE booting will load the correct files from our existing PXE server.  I was trying everything and anything to get it boot just in case I accidentally stumbled on the correct command and syntax.

Comment: Once again: Are you starting iPXE in UEFI mode? If you aren’t, you cannot launch EFI executables.

Comment: @DanielB I have no idea if iPXE was in UEFI mode?  How can I even tell?

Comment: In the “Features” list that iPXE shows, it must list _EFI_.

Answer (score 0):

[iPXE](https://ipxe.org/) seems like a solution here, by burning its
[bootable ISO image](http://boot.ipxe.org/ipxe.iso)
to CD-ROM or USB, if you can connect such media to this device.

You can use it to list all PXE servers on the network and select
the one to boot from.

Comment: How do I use iPXE? I made the bootable USB and booted from it and  got the CLI but all commands I tried had errors.  I need to know the exact commands to type on the CLI and the parameters.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://ipxe.org/docs). I've only read about this product, but never used it myself.

Comment: Documentation is pretty but not helpful.  Almost of the docs reference booting from a http or https server which is not what I want.  Our security officer would certainly notice a web server, and approval is a long process best avoided.